# incompatible types: org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient cannot be converted to org.apache.hc.client5.http.classic.HttpClient

Tags: java, spring-boot, compiler-errors

Am upgrading 'spring-boot-starter' version from 2.5.7 to 3.0.2 then am getting compilation error saying like
'incompatible types: org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient cannot be converted to org.apache.hc.client5.http.classic.HttpClient'

can you please some one help on this?

Thanks in advance.

am expecting the resolution for the problem

Answer (score 3):

Anyone can try like this who are facing this issue, following code worked for me in Spring Boot version **3.1.1** with httpclient5

**httpclient5**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents.client5</groupId>
    <artifactId>httpclient5</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.1</version>
</dependency>
```

**Code:**

```
@Bean
public RestTemplate restTemplate()  throws KeyStoreException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyManagementException {
    final RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

    SSLContext sslContext = SSLContextBuilder.create()
            .loadTrustMaterial((X509Certificate[] certificateChain, String authType) -> true)  // <--- accepts each certificate
            .build();

    Registry<ConnectionSocketFactory> socketRegistry = RegistryBuilder.<ConnectionSocketFactory>create()
            .register(URIScheme.HTTPS.getId(), new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(sslContext))
            .register(URIScheme.HTTP.getId(), new PlainConnectionSocketFactory())
            .build();

    HttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create()
            .setConnectionManager(new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager(socketRegistry))
            .setConnectionManagerShared(true)
            .build();
    
    ClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(httpClient);
    restTemplate.setRequestFactory(requestFactory);
    return restTemplate;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient is part of the older Apache HttpComponents library, which has been deprecated in favour of the newer Apache HttpComponents Client 5 library.

Here you can find more details:
https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-5.2.x/migration-guide/migration-to-classic.html

> There will be compilation errors due to API incompatibilities between
> version series 4.x and 5.x mostly related to SSL/TLS and timeout
> settings and CloseableHttpClient instance creation. Remove old
> org.apache.http imports and re-import HttpClient classes from
> org.apache.hc.httpclient5 package namespace.

If you are using version 5.x of the library, you will need to make sure that you are using the correct classes and interfaces from that version, rather than the older ones from version 4.x.